# Unable to view variables sent to .php from .html

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to POST form data from my html page to PHP, but am unable to see the data which I've posted.  Kindly help.   This is my code:

Code for html file:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Intro Page.
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form action="receive.php" method="POST">


      Name:<input type="text" name="username">
      Password:<input type="text" name="password">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </body>
</html>
```

And the code for my receive.php file is:

```
<?php

$name=$pass="";

$name=$_POST["username"];
$pass=$_POST["password"];



if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{

  $name= test_input($_POST["username"]);
  $pass= test_input($_POST["password"]);
}

function test_input($data)
{
  $data=trim($data);
  $data=stripslashes($data);
  $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

echo $name;
echo $pass;

?>
```

Comment: open the receive.php directly  and check first php working or not ? and let me know what kind of error showing

Comment: did you placed your code in apache root directory ?

Comment: You are missing your closing `</form>`.

Comment: @jothi  I've changed the code as per stated by you.   In the form, in the "action", I've mentioned "receive.php".    I've placed the php file in "htdocs"  folder of xampp.   When I'm inputting any value, it says that file could not be located.

Comment: @jothi I've changed the action to "/C:/xampp/htdocs/receive.php".  Now it doesn't show any error and redirects to the receive file.   But shows nothing.

Comment: your code is working fine i've checked please check if your **recieve.php ** is reachabe.

Comment: did you started your xampp ? properly ? i mean php started ?

Comment: .html file and  .php file or same directory or different directory ?

Comment: Make sure in htdocs create a folder , inside the folder run the files...

Comment: @jothi,  I have started my xampp properly.   My .html file is in a folder in desktop and the .php file is in the c:\xampp\htdocs\receive.php.

Comment: that is what wrong . you have to place both into inside the htdocs .its work charm

Comment: @krishna,  I have placed the php inside the htdocs folder

Comment: place the both file into under htdocs

Comment: in that htdocs create one folder name as your wish

Comment: @jothi,  I've now put both files in htdocs folder

Comment: creating files directly in htdocs folder , not good, you have to create folder inside htdocs

Comment: and make sure both files in same folder

Comment: But still I'm unable to see any data in the browser for the php file.

Comment: is there any error ? what showing there ?

Comment: @jothi  No, There is no error.  After I enter the username and password, it gets redirected to the php page but it does not echo them.  I mean it does not show them on screen.  I get a blank screen.

Comment: please review my answer below...simply posting variable to php page, you should use get method..

Comment: put this code in top of php file to know the error    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: @Krishna,  We can use both post and get.  But either ways it should show the variables on my page.   I tried doing get also. But still showing nothing.

Comment: try with my code below.

Comment: @jothi No errors I tried to put an echo "shubham" but it doesn't display that also.

Comment: @krishna Tried your code, the output is: Welcome.... Your email address is... But not getting any values.

Comment: you just remove the all code  and paste it <?php  echo phpinfo(); ?>  open the page directly

Comment: did u started xamp server...mysql and apache

Comment: @jothi.  I removed the code and pasted that code.  It shows the php version 5.6.19.

Comment: @krishna .yes I started.

Comment: try this <?php echo "php working fine "; ?>  open the page directly

Comment: shows "php working fine"

Comment: when I start php directly it echos the things well but when I am trying to post any data and display it on a php file, it doesn't work.

Comment: @jothi shows "php working fine"

Comment: put the both file code into receive.php and try it

Comment: @jothi It works fine in the same file and shows shows the variables also which I input.  But I have named it "receive.php" .   I want to open it in the html format.   I mean I want my first page to be .html for my website.

Comment: @jothi. Can I have the first page of my website a .php file?

Comment: its not a issue .php

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by changing your form submit button to have a name:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit>
```

Allowing you to modify your PHP to look like:

```
function test_input($data) {
    $data=trim($data);
    $data=stripslashes($data);
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

$name=$pass = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
    $pass = test_input($_POST['pass']);
}

echo $name;
echo $pass;
```

You're probably receiving errors that you don't know about. While debugging/writing your code, it's best to have error reporting turned on by having the following at the top of your PHP scripts:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1); // or E_ALL
```

Comment: I tried changing the code but still I can't see the value of $name and $pass  in the browser when the html file gets redirected to the php page in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

1)check php installed properly

2)know that file place under apache root directory

**TESTING :**

open the receive.php directly and check first php working or not.

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit"  name="form1_submit" value="submit">
```

as per @kunruh mentioned that

```
You are missing your closing </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$name=$pass="";

function test_input($data)
{
   $data=trim($data);
   $data=stripslashes($data);
   $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

//you have to check the value post like because some times more than one form in your html means it make conflict so you have to use name isset .

if(isset($_POST['form1_submit'])) {
 {

    $name= test_input($_POST["username"]);
    $pass= test_input($_POST["password"]);

   echo $name;
   echo $pass;
  }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the receive.php file placed near the html file. Eg:

if the html file is place in the following path /var/www/html/YOUR_HTML_FILE.html

then the receive.php file should also be placed in the same path /var/www/html/receive.php. Else, mention the correct path in the form action `<form action="/var/www/html/receive.php" method="POST">`. Also change the password field from **text** to **password**.

```html
Text field - <input type="text" name="password">
<br>
Password field - <input type="password" name="password">
```